# Do I need to renew the Institutional Recovery Key certificate with FileVault

Tags: security, filevault, certificate, mobile-device-management

We plan to roll out FileVault via Apple's own MDM (Server.app). I already have some test-computers enrolled.

When I look at the certificate used for the Institutional Recovery Key, it expires in March 2019. It's a self signed certificate ([created like this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202385)).

Do I need to renew this certificate? I can't find any info on this.

Comment: You will need to renew. I’m on the operational end of certificates (installing certificates in profiles on iOS and tvOS devices through a third-party MDM and Apple Configurator) but I don’t create or maintain them myself. Out-of-date certificates can cause pain and anguish.

Comment: For macOS in this case it is not needed, since you're using a self-signed certificate. It was confirmed by Rich Trouton's talk on [managing FileVault on High Sierra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EoIKQ5ciL5k).

Comment: I think the lack of expiration control on a self signed certificate is an error. What is the purpose of the expiration date in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure. As far as I know it's an standard self-signed SSL certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to test this by setting a test Mac and then starting it with a date set to April the 1st of 2019 (just after your certificate expiration date).
Of course, for this test to work you will need to deactivate any automatic time synchronization:

```
System Preferences... > Date & Time
```

turn off:

```
Set Date & Time automatically
```

Comment: Good thinking! I'll try and let you know.

Comment: Indeed. It is not needed.